# Macos not searching Ubuntu file share

Tags: macos, network, unix, search, smb

I have a ubuntu server 22.04 setup and it is sharing files using samba.

The mac computer can connect to it and use the files just fine. My problem comes in when i try and search for a file or folder that it will just not work on mac. Other windows or linux machines on the network searches just fine. I have use elasticsearch with fs Crawler in the past but it doesn't work well it will search one day and not the next or even search now and 5 min later the search doesn't work anymore.Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and am currently trialling Commander One file manager for Mac, which seems to be consistent and accurate with searching.  My Ubuntu 22.04 server is a VM being backed up by Veeam, so I also have the issue that Veeam does not yet support Ubuntu 22.04 for Guest file level recovery.  Veeam will restore the entire VM (tested it), so I can wait until Veeam V12 is released for file level support.

Good luck!

Colin

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the macOS app EasyFind from [DEVON Technologies](https://www.devontechnologies.com/support/download?id=download). It works extremely well with non-Apple file systems.

We used it for quite a number of years to search through literally tens of thousands of PDF files in hundreds of folders which were stored on a Windows server.

Best of all -- it is free!

<sub>NOTE: I have no financial or other association with DEVON Technologies</sub>